# Deployment of Nuxt (with SSR) and NestJS on the same Node.js instance

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, nestjs, plesk

I am going to deploy a simple app with Nuxt on frontend and NestJS on backend. Both of them need Node.js to run.

I saw an example on localhost with Nuxt SSR and NestJS using different ports. However I need to deploy it on the Plesk VPS server which has only one Node.js instance for the domain.

My question is: is it possible to run Nuxt (SSR feature) and NestJS (API) on the same Node.js instance in production? If so, how to achieve it? Or maybe I think totally wrong and the right way of doing is totally different in this case?

Comment: I would recommend splitting the front-end and backend especially if you're running both in SSR because the load will be pretty decent. Is it feasible? Probably but I don't have a how-to tutorial for that specific case.

Comment: Thank you for your input. They are splitted in terms of folders, but I want to host them on the same domain, so that API is called just with: https://my-url.com/api So my question is about using the same node.js instance with the same port number by SSR (Nuxt) and API framework (Nestjs).

Comment: hi @paul321 did you figure this one out? 18 months later and I still can't seem to find a recommended setup for this structure.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Builder` is available for Nuxt 2.

```js
import { Builder, Nuxt } from 'nuxt';
```

https://github.com/Goopil/nest-nuxt-starter

I am still looking for such configuration in nuxt 3. So can/will post once I figure same in Nuxt 3.